# Issue with image alpha channels in Chrome, but dependent on the monitor

Tags: google-chrome, display

I'm at a complete loss as to where to find an answer for this, so I thought I'd try here...

I noticed recently that some images with alpha channels are displaying incorrectly.  However, I just noticed it only happens on my primary monitor and not on the secondary monitor.  If I see it in Chrome, I can drag the window to my secondary monitor and it disappears!

Here's what it looks like with the issue (look around the yellow "o"):

[image: google logo with alpha channel issue]

And here it is on my secondary monitor:

[image: google logo normal]

I've noticed this on several different websites, but only within Google Chrome.

I just noticed that if the window is mostly within my secondary monitor but the image is on the primary it's fine!  So, it renders properly on the primary monitor if the window is part way between the two monitors but mostly on the secondary.

Comment: Is your secondary monitor connected to a different GPU than your primary?

Comment: @AndroidDev - I'm using a laptop with an integrated Intel GPU, so I think both displays are using that single GPU.

Comment: Hmm... in that case, since it only happens in Chrome, (did you test Firefox?) I'd be tempted to say this is a Chrome bug and you should report it to the Chrome devs...